# AngularJS - Stuck Handling response after $resource.save (expecting json)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-resource

Hello first of all thanks for your support,

I getting started with angular and I am trying to use conmsume data from an API for my app. I am having a  few problems with this. 
First of all CORS:

To run local http server I am using the one that comes with node.js (using http-server command). 
I am using http://www.mocky.io/ to test  the app. I've generated differents (with headers I've found around the net that are supposed to fix it) response there to try to fix CORS (always getting preflight error) but nothing seems to work. 
I have added this to my save method (inside a factory):

```
save: {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }
}
```

If I use a Chrome extension called CORS I can bypass that and receive response but then I am not able to manage the promise and get the data inside the response. I would like to be able to show the response's json on the view.

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
    var promise = null;
    promise = CheckFactory.save($scope.partner).$promise;
    $scope.result = promise.data;
}
```

This functions sends the data from the form to the factory and perform the request but then I am lost and do not know how to manage the data I need from the response.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to put `.then` function over your `save` method call promise. So that will call `.then` function's once data save request gets completed.

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
    CheckFactory.save($scope.partner).$promise
    //it will called success callback when save promise resolved.
    .then(function(data){ //success
       $scope.result = data;
    }, function(error){ //error
    });
}
```

Comment: Sweet :) this worked flawlessly. 
Anything about getting this work with CORS? I do not want to use Chrome extension if possible but I am not able to do so. 
Thanks for your ultra fast response.

Comment: @Nikos4Life you have to set up CORS on server side as well & while making request to header you have to pass some headers with each request :)

Comment: Deleted my answer - don't worry be happy Pankaj! :)

Comment: @daan.desmedt see man, I think you took it personally, I commented there, because this is how SO works.. :)

Comment: Don't worry, i'm really crying :p No you are absolute right! Should of send a edit proposal to your answer. :)

Comment: @PankajParkar thanks but not sure if following you on this. My request made by my angular app has to have some special headers? As I am using mocky.io's web to resolve the request with data through my local http-server do you mean I do have to configure my http-server to allow CORS? And after that Do I have to make custom response mock in mocky.io?

Comment: @Nikos4Life I'm sure you are missing something, I'd say that look at [this link] to configure CORS on server